# FirstRun info in JSON (WP)

Tags: json, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

i have a problem with the info of a JSON in Windows Phone.
I want to show if the app is running for the first time, and if not, don't show anything.

This is my function to show info on the JSON:

```
async void NavigationService_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.IsNavigationInitiator
            || !e.IsNavigationInitiator && e.NavigationMode != NavigationMode.Back)
        {
            var navigationInfo = new
            {
                Mode = e.NavigationMode.ToString(),
                From = this.BackStack.Any() ? this.BackStack.Last().Source.ToString() : string.Empty,
                Current = e.Uri.ToString(), 
            };

            var jsonData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(navigationInfo);

            await this.currentApplication.Client.PageView(jsonData);
        }
    }
```

I want to add one more thing where is Mode, From and Current. I want to add IsFirstRun that give as True if it's the first time i open the app.

I've seen this for firstRun function, but i don't know how to put it in my code.

```
public static bool IsFirstRun()
{
    if (!settings.Contains(FIRST_RUN_FLAG)) //First time running
    {
        settings.Add(FIRST_RUN_FLAG, false);
        return true;
    }
    return false;   
}
```

I need help... thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is pretty simple if you want to create a flag for First Run,

In App.xaml.cs

Look for a function named

```C#
// Code to execute when the application is launching (eg, from Start)
// This code will not execute when the application is reactivated
private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
{
}
```

What we want to do is create a flag inside this function and only set it to true if it doesn't exist.  Like so.

```C#
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;  // include this namespace in App.xaml.cs

// Code to execute when the application is launching (eg, from Start)
// This code will not execute when the application is reactivated
private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("first_run"))
    {
        IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Add("first_run", true);
    }
    else
    {
        // set the flag to flase
        IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["first_run"] = false;
    }

    // save
    IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
}
```

Now if you want to do something on first run all you have to do is check the settings again like so:

```C#
bool first_run = (bool) IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["first_run"];
```

---

For debugging cases you will probably want to remove the flag so it will hit first_run again by doing this

```
// remove the flag and save
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Remove("first_run");
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
```